# in HTML, how do I make a dropdown with pictures when its in a list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

thank you for trying to help me!

Here is my current line

```
<li><a href="#Language">*LanguageHERE*</a></li>
```

I want it to be a dropdown menu when I hover/press it where it is flags for all languages avaible, but I don't know how to create a dropdown menu with images? could someone help me?

Comment: Please add more details to your question, try be specific and add all code you have tried. thanks

Comment: read this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Answer (score 0):

easy example

```
<li>
<a href="#Language">
<img name="ob" src="../menu/1.jpg" onmouseover="ob.src='../menu/2.jpg'" onmouseout="ob.src='../menu/1.jpg'" onclick="ob.src='../menu/3.jpg';" border="0">
</a>
</li>
```

but, I prefer bootstrap 
[enter link description here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav)